# Ad hoc graphics primitives-like objects

Tags: graphics, plotting

`Sphere` is one of the three-dimensional graphics primitives available in Mathematica and can be easily used to created very useful images. For instance, in the figure below I created three images of an ellipsoidal object that is lit from a fixed direction and it is then just rotated around the z-axis.

```
GraphicsRow[
    Table[
        Graphics3D[
        Rotate[Scale[{GrayLevel[.7], Sphere[]}, {1, 1.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], 
        i Degree, {0, 0, 1}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
        AspectRatio -> 1, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
        ViewPoint -> Front, SphericalRegion -> True, 
        Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, ImageScaled[{0, 0, 1}]}}
    ], {i, {0, 45, 90}}]]
```

[image: ellipsoidalObject]

Suppose that instead of using the ellipsoidal object I would like to use an object like this bump:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: bump]

Is there a way to create a "graphics primitive" object of the bump, so as to just use it instead of `Sphere` in the above example?

I suppose there should be a way to extract all the polygons specifying the shape of the bump, but I couldn't find a way to do it. Any other approach is also more than welcome.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The result of `Plot3D` and related functions is something of the form `Graphics3D[primitives, options]`, so to extract the graphics primitives you can simply take the first part of the plot. These can then be manipulated similar to `Sphere[]` in your example, e.g.

```
plot = Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}][[1]];

GraphicsRow[
 Table[Graphics3D[
   Rotate[Scale[{GrayLevel[.7], plot}, {1, 1.5, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], 
    i Degree, {0, 0, 1}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> Front, SphericalRegion -> True, 
   Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, 
      ImageScaled[{0, 0, 1}]}}], {i, {0, 45, 90}}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice use of [[1]] to extract the GraphicsComplex from the plot!

Comment: Or slightly more transparently: `Cases[(* stuff *), _GraphicsComplex, Infinity] // First`.

Comment: Or if you are baffled by  `GraphicsComplex`, try `Cases[Normal[plot], _Polygon, Infinity]` which will return the (many many) constituting polygons.

Answer (score 15):

I think what you're looking for is [`BSplineSurface`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineSurface.html). For your given example, try:

```
cpts = Table[{x, y, Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)]}, {x, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y, -2, 2, 
    0.1}];

Graphics3D[BSplineSurface[cpts], Boxed -> False]
```

Which gives:

[image: Mathematica graphics]