# Use output from Plot3D as an object in Graphics3D that I can transform

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to draw up an optical system where I can show an example of wavefront error on an exit pupil. It would be great if I could take the results of a 3D function from Plot3D and use it as a graphics object that I could transform to fit into my Graphis3D drawing.  Below is some code that does not work but it shows a very simple case of what I would like to be able to do.

```
pic = Plot3D[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 <= 20]];

Graphics3D[{Rotate[pic, \[Pi]/4, {1, 1, 1}], 
        Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}]}]
```

Comment: `Show[{Graphics3D@Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}], pic}]` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You could use `ParametricPlot3D[]` instead, e.g. `ParametricPlot3D[RotationTransform[Pi/4, {1, 1, 1}][{x, y, Sin[x] Sin[y]}] // Evaluate, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, RegionFunction -> ((#1^2 + #2^2 <= 20) &)]`...

Comment: Yes I realize there are options where I can change the orientation of my function in Plot3D or ParametricPlot3D etc or even use Epilog. But my full problem is I want to place surface functions inside a very complex Graphic3D "Drawing"

Comment: Kind of similar question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3186/ad-hoc-graphics-primitives-like-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just changing `pic` to `pic[[1]]` should work, that's where the `GraphicsComplex`for the plot is.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{
   Rotate[pic[[1]], Dynamic[v], {1, 1, 1}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5, 5}}]}
  , PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}], {v, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: As for why this works, you can always run `FullForm[pic]` and see that it's really just an expression of the form `Graphics3d[....]` which the front end interprets as an image. Therefore any manipulation that works on any normal expression also works on the graphics.

Comment: Very nice. I tried something similar to this but I took the other parts of pic and tried to rebuild the Graphics3D[GraphisComplex[]] object. after rotating pic[[1]]. Thank you!

Comment: @jVincent, yea I saw it had `Head` `Graphics3D` but the error given without `[[1]]` was `Graphics is not a Graphics3D primimtive or directive` so somewhere along the line I presume there must be a `Graphics`

Comment: Oh I get it know, the `Graphics3D` is the entire graphics structure, and that's why `Show` is even used at all

Comment: @ssch Yea, just to recap, if you run `Graphics3D[pic]` what you end up with is: `Graphics3D[Graphics3D[GraphicsComplext[...]]` (Too many layers of Graphics3D!) but when you do `Graphics3D[pic[[1]]]` you end up with `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplext[...]`.