# How do I draw a hemisphere?

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

I want to draw a solid or partially transparent hemisphere above a partially transparent cuboid object in `Graphics3D`.  However, I do not know how to do this such that only half the sphere is drawn.  Here's what the object looks like with the full sphere:

```
SphereOpacity = 0.5;
CuboidOpacity = 0.5;
SphereColor = Blue;
CuboidColor = Orange;
Graphics3D[{SphereColor, Opacity[SphereOpacity], Sphere[{0, 0, 0.5}, 0.5], 
            CuboidColor, Opacity[CuboidOpacity], Cuboid[{-5, -5, 0}, {5, 5, 0.5}]}, 
            Boxed -> False
]
```

[image: figure]

How might I proceed to "remove" the bottom half the sphere embedded in the cuboid primitive?  In general, is there a way to not render/draw parts of a graphics primitive conditioned intersection with another primitive?

Comment: One method (using `RegionFunction`) is shown [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/how-to-draw-a-great-circle-on-a-sphere/16434#16434).

Comment: If you're interested in this type of geometry, you might enjoy [Yu-sung Chang's presentation](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/search.php?Search=Scan&x=0&y=0).

Comment: @cormullion Thanks, I'd love to take a look but your link doesn't quite work?

Comment: This seems related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3186/121

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, 
                 {u, 0, π}, {v, 0, π},             
                 Mesh -> None, 
                 Boxed -> False, 
                 Axes -> None
]
```

[image: some hemisphere]

```
r = 0.5;
d = {0, 0, 0.5}
sphere = ParametricPlot3D[r {Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + d, 
            {u, -π/2, π/2}, {v, -π/2, π/2}, 
            Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None][[1]];

SphereOpacity = 0.5;
CuboidOpacity = 0.5;
SphereColor = Blue;
CuboidColor = Orange;
Graphics3D[{SphereColor, Opacity[SphereOpacity], sphere, CuboidColor, 
            Opacity[CuboidOpacity], Cuboid[{-5, -5, 0}, {5, 5, 0.5}]}, 
           Boxed -> False]
```

[image: hemisphere and box]

Comment: +1 -- but it's a little bit harder to use this technique to draw an *arbitrary* hemisphere. :-)

Comment: @whuber Not with help of `GeometricTransformation`, I'd say.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Just for the sake of future readers, you mean GeometricTransformation right?  In any case this is great!

Comment: @QuadraticU Roger that

Comment: I took the liberty to make this into a function, see my edit

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion It should be a standalone answer.

Answer (score 12):

This peculiar method works in *Mathematica* versions 7 (thanks, Mr. Wizard!) and 8, but apparently no longer in version 9 onwards (per rm and Reb.Cabin):

```
Graphics3D[{CapForm["Round"], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: half a ball]

(I know `CapForm["Round"]` can be omitted, since it's the default; I just wanted to indicate that it's the reason for this behavior.)

Replace the `1` with your desired radius. As has been noted, if you need to put your hemispheres into an arbitrary position/orientation, `GeometricTransformation[]` comes in handy.

---

A workaround suggested by Pickett for version 9 involves a slight perturbation of one of the endpoints, like so:

```
With[{r = 1, ε = $MachineEpsilon},
     Graphics3D[{CapForm["Round"], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, ε r}}, {0, r}]}, 
                Boxed -> False]]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work in v9...

Comment: What does the result look like, then?

Comment: Just a blank image

Comment: @rm, for completeness: the other `CapForm[]`s also give a blank image?

Comment: Well, it just doesn't work with two identical points... but using e.g. `Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {10^(-10), 0, 0}}, {0, 1}]` one can get the right shape even in v9

Comment: @C.E., I included your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @J.M. Yes, they all give a blank image. The perturbation works though, except for `"Butt"`, which gives a blank image.

Comment: Confirmed that everything in this answer and its comments is still true in V10.2.0.0, i.e., the original doesn't show anything and the workarounds do.

Answer (score 12):

To show that there's more than one way to skin a cat, here's another primitive-based method, using [NURBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) surfaces to render a hemisphere:

```
With[{r = 1}, 
     Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[],
                 BSplineSurface[Outer[Append[First[#1] #2, Last[#1]] &, 
                       r {{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}},
                       {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}}, 1], 
                                SplineClosed -> {False, True}, SplineDegree -> 2, 
                                SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
                                                {0, 0, 0, 1/4, 1/2, 1/2, 3/4, 1, 1, 1}}, 
                                SplineWeights -> Outer[Times, {1, 1/Sqrt[2], 1},
                                                       {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]]},
                BaseStyle -> {BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions ->
                              {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 40}}}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: another hemisphere]

Change `r` to vary the radius; the control points in the first argument of `BSplineSurface[]` can be translated and rotated, if the hemisphere needs to be positioned/oriented differently.

If you're interested in this sort of thing, you can refer to work by Piegl and Tiller, e.g. [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/38.35537) and [their book](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=7dqY5dyAwWkC&pg=PA340).

---

Here's another NURBS representation of a hemisphere:

```
With[{r = 1}, 
     Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], 
                 BSplineSurface[Outer[Insert[First[#1] #2, Last[#1], 2] &, 
                                      r {{0, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},
                                      {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, 1],
                                SplineDegree -> 2, 
                                SplineKnots -> {{0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 1, 1},
                                                {0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1, 1, 1}},
                                SplineWeights -> Outer[Times, {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1},
                                                              {1, 1/2, 1/2, 1}]]}, 
                BaseStyle -> {BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions ->
                              {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 40}}}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: still another hemisphere]

**N.B.** The previous version of this answer featured `BSplineSurface[]` objects with noticeable blemishes; this turned out to be due to insufficient internal sampling. Adding the option `BaseStyle -> {BSplineSurface3DBoxOptions -> {Method -> {"SplinePoints" -> 40}}}` (similar to what Mr. Wizard did [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84247)) minimizes the blemishes to a barely noticeable spot.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of the blemish?

Comment: I haven't figured out how. Weirdly, if I use B-splines for the *full* sphere, I don't see nasty spots at the poles.

Comment: Too bad; this method is smoother than the `Tube` method which shows facets.

Comment: Okay, I found an alternative; the (antipodal) blemishes are now at the rim, but that might be more acceptable to some.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it took more than two years, but I finally got rid of those blemishes. ;)

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks for linking to my post.  You already had my vote and I can't vote again.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I know. ;) I was just looking through my old posts and suddenly was reminded of your post that I linked to.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another simple way to draw a hemisphere that makes use of the symmetry axis:

```
hemisphere = 
  First@RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[1 - r^2], {r, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None];
```

Here you can vary the option `PlotPoints` if needed, to get a more or less dense polygon mesh.

I also extract the contents of the `Graphics3D` object before using it. This needs to be done whenever you plan to combine the result of a `Plot3D`-related function with other objects in a single `Graphics3D` (and be able to do translations, rotations, etc. on the individual objects). To show how it works, here is an example:

```
plant = First@ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "PottedPlant"}];

Graphics3D[{
  Translate[
   Scale[Rotate[
     {Brown,
      hemisphere},
     {{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}], 25],
   {0, 0, 28}],
  {Darker[Green], plant}
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral",
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image: pottedplant]

**Edit: a raster based approach in version 9**

Motivated by cormullion's answer, here is another way:

```
data3D = With[{reso = .05},
   Table[Boole[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1
          && 
       z >= 0 || (-5 < x < 5) && (-5 < y < 5) && (-0.5 < z < 
         0)], {x, -2, 2, reso}, {y, -2, 2, reso}, {z, -2, 2, reso}]
   ];

Image3D[data3D]
```

[image: image3d]

The `Image3D` command is not available before version 9, and its rasterized output may not be desirable - but it has a certain appeal in that you get something similar to a `RegionPlot3D`, but with a more volumetric appearance.

Answer (score 6):

Since no-one has done a `RegionPlot3D`, I'll do one.

```
RegionPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1
   &&
   z >= 0 ||  
   (-5 < x < 5) && (-5 < y < 5) && (-0.5 < z < 0),
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotPoints -> 120, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[Yellow, 12], Opacity[0.8]],
 Boxed -> False,
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {{5, 5, 4}, {2, 2, 0}}}},
 BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ImageSize -> 600,
 Axes -> False]
```

[image: plot]

`RegionPlot3D` plots always seem to have that 'home-made' look about them...

Comment: (+1) That gave me another idea: `Image3D`...

Comment: It's also a bit slower than the other methods; it may be worth it to get the neat little "weld" seam, and that little seam might be really helpful if you want to tet-volume-mesh or other discretize this composite shape.

Answer (score 3):

#### [`ClipPlanes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html)

In versions 10.0+, we can simply replace `Sphere[...]` with `{ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, 1, -.5}, Sphere[...]}` to get the desired output:
:

```
Graphics3D[{SphereColor, Opacity[SphereOpacity],
  {ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, 1, -.5}, Sphere[{0, 0, 0.5}, 1]},
  CuboidColor, Opacity[CuboidOpacity], Cuboid[{-5, -5, 0}, {5, 5, 0.5}]},
 Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Grid[
 Table[
      Graphics3D[{ClipPlanes -> s p, Sphere[]}, 
        PlotLabel -> Style[s p, 16], ImageSize -> Small], 
    {s, {1, -1}}, {p, Append[0] /@ IdentityMatrix[3]}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using whuber's method, we can generate a hemisphere with elevation $\alpha$ and horizon $\theta$ using ContourPlot as follows:

```
α = 0;
θ = 0;

normal = Cross[{Cos[θ], Sin[θ], 0}, {Cos[α] (-Sin[θ]), Cos[α] Cos[θ], Sin[α]}];

ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
 Contours -> {1}, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, normal.{x, y, z} >= 0]]
```

Comment: This was a bit too long to leave as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I made a function out of Sjoerd's answer because I feel the need to make a hemisphere is something that more people experience.

```
hemisphere[n_, r_, origin_ : {0, 0, 0}, closed_ : False] := 
 Module[{R, defaultplotstyle},
  R = RotationTransform[{{0, 1, 0}, -n}];
  defaultplotstyle = ("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
         Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]))[[1]];
  ParametricPlot3D[
   {
    R[r {Cos[\[Pi] u] Sin[\[Pi] v], Sin[\[Pi] u] Sin[\[Pi] v], 
       Cos[\[Pi] v]}],
    If[closed, R[r v {Cos[2 \[Pi] u], 0, Sin[2 \[Pi] u]}], 
     Sequence[{}]]
    },
   {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> {defaultplotstyle, defaultplotstyle}
   ]
  ]
```

Here `n` is a normal vector such that the open end of the hemisphere points in the direction of the normal, `r` is the radius, `origin` is the center of the hemisphere and `closed` can be set to true if you want the open end to be closed off.

Result:

[image]

Source for getting default plotstyle: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172149/45428

Answer (score 2):

One could also make use of Region and ImplicitRegion:

```
Region[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]]
```

The previous object can be used in the following way:

```
hemisphere = 
  Region[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 5 && z >= 0, {x, y, z}]];
Show[
 {
  hemisphere,
  Graphics3D[{Red, Opacity[0.5], Cuboid[{-5, -5, 0}, {5, 5, 0.5}]},
   Boxed -> False]
  }
 ]
```

Results look as shown on the next images; the first one is the actual hemisphere and the second one is the hemisphere on a cuboid.

[image: This the hemisphere object]
[image: This is the hemisphere on a cuboid]
Cheers,