# Creating a tube with custom caps

Tags: graphics3d, vector

I need a tube with only one end capped.  I can do this relatively easily with:

```
monoTube[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_] := {
  EdgeForm[None],
  Cylinder[{pt1, pt2}, r],
  Sphere[pt2, r]}
```

I would also like the entire object to have the length `EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]`, which means I really need a `pt3` lying on the object's path that is closer to `pt1` than `pt2` is by the distance `r`.  While I know this is a simple vector operation, I do not know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
monoTube [{pt1_, pt2_}, r_] := {EdgeForm[None], Cylinder[{pt1, pt2}, r], Sphere[pt2, r]}
monoTube1[{pt1_, pt2_}, r_] :=   
                          With[{s = (Norm[pt2 - pt1] - r) Normalize[pt2 - pt1] +  pt1}, 
                              {EdgeForm[None], Cylinder[{pt1, s}, r], Sphere[s, r]}]

Graphics3D[{monoTube [{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1], 
            monoTube1[{{2, 0, -1}, {2, 0, 1}}, 1]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That's what I'm looking for; clearly, I need to crack open a linear algebra book.

Answer (score 3):

Use two `Tube[]`s:

```
monoTube[{p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ}, r_?NumericQ] := 
        Module[{h = 1 + $MachineEpsilon^(3/4), pm, t},
               t = r/EuclideanDistance[p1, p2];
               pm = t p1 + (1 - t) p2;
               {{CapForm[None], Tube[{p1, pm}, r]}, 
                Tube[{t h p1 + (1 - t h) p2, pm}, {0, r}]}]

Graphics3D[monoTube[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 1}}, 0.1]]
```

[image: tube with a single cap]

Comment: Neat idea.  I did not know one could obtain `pm` the way you have. Do you know why `h` is needed?

Comment: @bob, prolly should've linked to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25020) to begin with. :)