# 3D printing cardioid

Tags: graphics3d, image3d, 3d-printing

I am hoping to 3D print some `simple` cardioid pictures, like the following:

```
myplot2[k_: 2, n_: 60] := With[    {a = Exp[2 Pi*I*Range@n/n]},    Graphics[     GraphicsComplex[      Dynamic@       ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]], {Line@Transpose@Partition[Range[2 n], n],       Thick, Circle[]}]]    ];
test = myplot2[2, 60 ]


extrudeImage[image_] :=   Block[{res, img},img = DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[image, 0.7], 500];    res = ImageMesh[ColorNegate[img]];    RegionProduct[res, Line[{{0.}, {50.}}]]];
testfor3d = extrudeImage[test]
Printout3D[testfor3d]
```

This seem like a bad output.

[image]

Using the solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4197/how-to-convert-a-2d-image-into-a-3d-graphics),

```
img = test;
g = MorphologicalGraph[img // MorphologicalBinarize, 
   VertexCoordinates -> Automatic, EdgeWeight -> Automatic];
edges = EdgeList[g];

vertices =   Thread[Rule[VertexList[g], PropertyValue[g, VertexCoordinates]]]; lines = ((edges /. vertices) /.     UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] :> Line[{a, b}]);
Graphics[lines]

Graphics3D[  Tube[#] & /@ (lines /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, 0, y})]
```

This then looks like just had a plastic surgery.

Any good workaround?

Comment: FWIW, you can drop the `Dynamic@` from the first argument of the `GraphicsComplex` in `myPlot`.  That was included for the `Manipulate` in the other post.  (Won't fix the problem.)

Comment: If you remove the `Dynamic@`, does this work for you?: `Graphics3D[First@test /. GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, o___] :> GraphicsComplex[PadRight[p, {Automatic, 3}], g /. {Line -> Tube, c_Circle -> Tube[Range@60 ~Append~ 1]}]]` -- I'm not real sure what works on a 3D printer or if you require each line to become a cuboid instead of a tube.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems your `MeshRegion` has degenerate `Prism` objects that aren't able to export. We can take the boundary instead and skip the repair phase.

```
Printout3D[RegionBoundary[testfor3d], Method -> "SkipModelRepair"]
```

[image]

---

Instead, here's a manual approach to construct your region.

First I'll turn the 2D graphic into a `BoundaryMeshRegion` by thickening the lines and joining them with a discretized `Annulus`.

```
lines = With[{k = 2, n = 60},
 With[{a = Exp[2. Pi*I*Range@n/n]}, 
  First@Normal[
   GraphicsComplex[ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]], 
    Line@Transpose@Partition[Range[2 n], n]]]]
];

thickenLine[Line[{p1_, p2_}], Δ_: .004] := Block[{p},
 p = Δ {1, -1} Reverse[Normalize[p2 - p1]];
 BoundaryMeshRegion[{p1 - p, p1 + p, p2 + p, p2 - p}, Line[{1, 2, 3, 4, 1}]]
]

envelope = RegionUnion @@ thickenLine /@ Most[lines];

boundary = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Annulus[{0, 0}, {.99, 1.01}], MaxCellMeasure -> .01];

cardioid2D = RegionUnion[boundary, envelope]
```

[image]

Next we go 3D with `RegionProduct`:

```
cardioid3D = RegionBoundary[RegionProduct[cardioid2D, Line[{{0.}, {.25}}]]]
```

[image]

And finally print:

```
Printout3D[cardioid3D]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just the start of an approach, but I have to admit, I got stuck.

```
radius = 0.03;
Graphics3D@
   MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeGraphics[test], 1] /. {Line[pts_] :> 
    Cylinder[PadRight[#, 3] & /@ pts, radius]};
obj = Import[Export["temp.stl", %]]
```

[image]

`Import@Export` does a nice job at generating a mesh (whereas `DiscretizeGraphics` does not, and I don't know why.  You will have to play with a `TransformedRegion` and `ScalingTransform` in order to obtain an object of suitable dimensions for printing. [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92073/7167) on capped tubes will make the ends a bit nicer and you'll have to think about how to hand the gap, because the answer eludes me.