# Why ClipPlane show a hollow object for a filled object? Realization of Wigner-Seitz cell or Brillouin Zone

Tags: graphics3d

For example, according to the doc, the `Ball` is a filled ball in 2D and 3D.

However,

```
Graphics3D[{Ball[]}, 
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}]]
```

Shows a hollow ball, the same as `Sphere`

[image]

What is wrong? How to make the cut object solid, and even better, can set the opacity to it?

**update**

What I actually want to do is to construct [Wigner-Seitz cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell) by series of middle cutting planes. like this

[image]

---

**update 2023-2-26**

I optimized @chyanog's solution, especially the `PlotRange` is adjusted automatically, otherwise it will give misleading result for long vector list.

```
BZview[bVecList_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{color, opacity, reduction},
  color = OptionValue["color"];
  opacity = OptionValue["opacity"];
  reduction = OptionValue["reduction"];
  pts = DeleteCases[
     Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 3], {0, 0, 0}] . (bVecList*(1 - reduction));
  Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[color], Opacity[opacity], 
    RegionIntersection[
     BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[HalfSpace[#, # . #/2], 
        PlotRange -> (3*MinMax /@ Transpose@pts)] & /@ pts]},
   Lighting -> "Neutral",Boxed -> False]
  ]
```

The "reduction" is essential for composing different BZ view when there are edges that coincide. For example, define

```
xx = 1.3;
aCon = {1., 0, 0};
bCon = {0, 1., 0};
cCon = {0, 0, xx};

aPrim = {0, 1./2, xx/2};
bPrim = {0, 1./2, -xx/2};
cPrim = {1., 0, 0};

primVecList = {aPrim, bPrim, cPrim};
conVecList = {aCon, bCon, cCon};
```

then

```
Show[BZview[conVecList], 
 BZview[primVecList, "color" -> Blue]]
```

gives

[image]

If we reduce the 2nd BZ a little bit.

```
Show[BZview[conVecList], 
 BZview[primVecList, "color" -> Blue, "reduction" -> 0.01]]
```

We get perfect

[image]

Comment: That's just how it is. All 3D graphics is made up of two-dimensional graphics primitives so it can't be in any other way.

Comment: @C.E. So how to make it solid? I mean at least, looks like solid when I cut it. I need it to be auto sealed with a face.

Comment: `Show[DiscretizeGraphics@Ball[], 
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}]]` not pretty but something.

Comment: @Kuba Oh, no, That's too rough, I need a smooth surface : )

Comment: You can use `Tube` like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25020/731). You could also cover the open end with a polygon.

Comment: Your second question is very different from your original question. Maybe you should rewrite the question and focus on the Wigner-Seitz cell question. Saying, perhaps, that you tried using `ClipPlanes` but it didn't work because the graphics primitive is not solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a better way to generate Wigner-Seitz Cell.

```
bVecList = {{-1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}};
pts = DeleteCases[Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, 3], {0, 0, 0}].bVecList;
AbsoluteTiming[reg = RegionIntersection[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[HalfSpace[#, #.#/2], 
  PlotRange -> 1] & /@ pts]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since, `ClipPlane` always gives a hollow object. So here is a workaround, Thanks to Rahul and Simon Woods's [great answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48486/high-quality-regionplot3d-for-logical-combinations-of-predicates) and their function `contourRegionPlot3D`

Here I show a way to generate Wigner-Seitz cell(a little slow, hope someone can give better solution)

```
Clear[planeEquation];
planeEquation[point_, perpendicularVec_] := 
  Module[{}, ({x, y, z} - point).perpendicularVec == 0];
planeEquation[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
  Module[{r = {x, y, z}}, Det[{r - p1, r - p2, r - p3}] == 0];
planeEquation[point_, {vec1_, vec2_}] := 
  Module[{p1 = point, p2 = point + vec1, p3 = point + vec2}, 
   planeEquation[p1, p2, p3]];

Clear[planeRegionEquation];
planeRegionEquation[anchorPoint_, planeEquation_] := 
  Module[{expr = planeEquation[[1]]},
   tmp = expr /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> anchorPoint];
   If[tmp == 0., Print["anchor point is right on the plane, error"]];
   If[tmp > 0, expr > 0, expr < 0]];

Clear[bisectionPlaneEquation];
bisectionPlaneEquation[p1_, p2_] := 
 Module[{midPoint = (p1 + p2)/2, perpendicularVec = p2 - p1}, 
  planeEquation[midPoint, perpendicularVec]]

Clear[contourRegionPlot3D];(*Simon Woods's function, a little modification for performance*)
contourRegionPlot3D[
  region_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, {z_, z0_, z1_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{}, 
  reg = LogicalExpand[
    region && x0 <= x <= x1 && y0 <= y <= y1 && z0 <= z <= z1];
  If[Head@reg === Or,
   preds = 
    Union@Cases[
      reg, _Greater | _GreaterEqual | _Less | _LessEqual, -1];
   Show@Table[
     ContourPlot3D[
      Evaluate[Equal @@ p], {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0, z1}, 
      RegionFunction -> 
       Function @@ {{x, y, z}, Refine[reg, p] && Refine[! reg, ! p]}, 
      opts], {p, preds}],
   preds = List @@ reg;
   Show@Table[
     ContourPlot3D[
      Evaluate[Equal @@ preds[[i]]], {x, x0, x1}, {y, y0, y1}, {z, z0,
        z1}, RegionFunction -> 
       Function @@ {{x, y, z}, And @@ Drop[preds, {i}]}, opts], {i, 1,
       Length@preds}]]];

bVecList = {{-1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}};
pts = DeleteCases[
    Tuples[ConstantArray[Range[-1, 1], 3]], {0, 0, 0}].bVecList;
conditionList = 
  planeRegionEquation[{0, 0, 0}, 
     bisectionPlaneEquation[{0, 0, 0}, #]] & /@ pts;
contourRegionPlot3D[
 And @@ conditionList, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None]
```

The above code gives below result and takes more than 3 seconds on my laptop.

[image]

And for example in my post, we can do this

```
contourRegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 && 
  planeRegionEquation[{1, 1, 1}, 
   planeEquation[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}]], {x, -1.1, 
  1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}, {z, -1.1, 1.1}, Mesh -> None]
```

this gives

[image]