# Plot the intersection of random half-spaces

Tags: regions, implicit

The code

```
n=30; (*number of points *)
points = RandomPoint[Sphere[],n]; (*points uniformly distributed on the unit sphere*)
p = ImplicitRegion[Table[points[[i]].{x,y,z}<=1,{i,1,n}],{x,y,z}]; (* intersection of corresponding half spaces *)
Region[p,PlotTheme->"Detailed"]
```

produces the following picture. It represents the intersection of 30 half spaces whose supporting hyperplanes are tangent to the sphere at random points.
[image: Intersection of 30 half spaces whose supporting hyperplanes are tangent to the sphere at random points]

The edges of that polyhedron are messed up. Is there something I can do to get a better picture ?

Comment: You can improve on it for example like this: `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[p, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]`. Decrease the `MaxCellMeasure` for a more accurate result. I will not post this as an answer as I am not personally satisfied with it. This will cause all flat faces of the region to be broken into a very large number of tiny cells as well. I would hope for a solution that uses the smallest possible number of faces.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this related to a Voronoi mesh? It looks quite similar. (I note that there is no 3D implementation of a Voronoi mesh in WL)

Comment: @CarlLange I don't think it is related to Voronoi mesh. In general the facet of a Voronoi cell are not all tangent to one sphere.

Comment: Another excellent answer which provides even more than I have asked here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14774/10686

Comment: Related:  [why-clipplane-show-a-hollow-object-for-a-filled-object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145477/why-clipplane-show-a-hollow-object-for-a-filled-object) , [find-the-3d-region-containing-the-origin-bounded-by-given-planes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198588/find-the-3d-region-containing-the-origin-bounded-by-given-planes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a given `j`,We can use `Hyperplane[points[[j]], points[[j]]]` to represent the plane which tangent to the unit sphere at point `points[[j]]`. Then we use another `n-1` `HalfSpace` to cut such plane and get one of such face.

```
n = 30;
points = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
faces = Table[
   RegionIntersection[Hyperplane[points[[j]], points[[j]]], 
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[HalfSpace[points[[i]], points[[i]]], {i, 
       Complement[Range[n], {j}]}]], {j, 1, n}];
DiscretizeRegion[#, MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-6] & /@ faces // Show
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Region is a rather quick and dirty plotting routine. More elaborate is RegionPlot:

n = 30;

```
SeedRandom[1];
points = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n]; p = 
 ImplicitRegion[
  Table[points[[i]].{x, y, z} <= 1, {i, 1, n}], {x, y, z}];
d = 1.3;
RegionPlot3D[{x, y, z} \[Element] p, {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, {z, -d, 
  d}, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: The `PlotPoints->150` option improves the result though slowing down the execution.

Comment: @user64494 - it is more efficient to use a combination of increasing both `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` rather than depending solely on `PlotPoints`. For example, compare the results and timing for `PlotPoints->100` versus `PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 6`

Answer (score 3):

Using `BoundaryDisctizeGraphics` to discretize the `HalfSpace` first
, then use `RegionIntersection`.

```
n = 30;
SeedRandom[1];
points = RandomPoint[Sphere[], n];
AbsoluteTiming[reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[HalfSpace[#, 1], PlotRange -> 2] & /@
  points // RegionIntersection]
```

> [image]

`Length[faces = MeshPrimitives[reg, 2]]`

> 30

Comment: Nice shot for `BoundaryDisctizeGraphics` with `HalfSpace`!