How to find extreme points of region from inequalities using Mathematica?
For the following inequalities how to find extreme points of the region using wolfram mathematica ?
$$ x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 \le 5 \\ -x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 \ \le 6 \\ x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0 $$

What are "extreme points" of this region?

@UlrichNeumann Presumably vertices of the convex hull of the boundary.


Here we only provide the numeric method. The same way as https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/267551/72111

We rewrite the 6 equations to HalfSpace.


Clear["Global`*"];
spaces = {HalfSpace[{1, 2, 1}, 5], HalfSpace[{-1, 1, 2}, 6], 
   HalfSpace[{-1, 0, 0}, 0], HalfSpace[{0, -1, 0}, 0], 
   HalfSpace[{0, 0, -1}, 0]};
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[#, PlotRange -> 15] & /@ spaces // 
   RegionIntersection;
pts = MeshPrimitives[reg, 0]
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], Cyan, reg}, Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], 
  MeshPrimitives[reg, 0]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True]


{Point[{5., 0., 0.}], Point[{0., 2.5, 0.}],  Point[{0., 1.33333, 2.33333}], Point[{1.33333, 0., 3.66667}],  Point[{0., 0., 3.}], Point[{0., -2.96059*10^-16, 0.}],  Point[{0., 0., 0.}]}



As @Ulrich pointed out, it depends on the definition of "extreme points". For example,
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

cons = {x1 + 2 x2 + x3 <= 5, -x1 + x2 + 2 x3 <= 6, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0};

vars = {x1, x2, x3};

If the extremes are determined by the min and max distance from the origin
#[{vars . vars, cons}, vars] & /@ {ArgMin, ArgMax}

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 0}} *)

If the extremes are the max values of the individual variables
ArgMax[{#, cons}, vars] & /@ vars

(* {{5, 0, 0}, {0, 5/2, 0}, {4/3, 0, 11/3}} *)

Or, if the extremes are the max values of the individual variables and the variables are restricted to integers,
ArgMax[{#, cons}, vars, Integers] & /@ vars

(* {{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 1}, {0, 0, 3}} *)

However, for integer values, the max values of the individual variables can occur at more than one point
max[n_] := MaximalBy[
  Select[
   Flatten[
    Table[{x1, x2, x3}, {x1, 0, 6}, {x2, 0, 6}, {x3, 0, 6}],
    2],
   (And @@ cons) /. Thread[vars -> #] &],
  #[[n]] &]

Flatten[max /@ Range[3], 1]

(* {{5, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}, {1, 0, 3}, {2, 0, 3}} *)


Here alternative to @BobHanlon's interesting answer
reg = ImplicitRegion[x1 + 2 x2 + x3 <= 5 && -x1 +  x2 + 2 x3 <= 6 && x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 &&x3 > 0, {x1, x2, x3}]
BoundingRegion[reg](*Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {5, 5/2, 11/3}]*)

Show[Region[reg], Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], BoundingRegion[reg]}]]



Since the inequalities $$ x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 \le 5 \\ -x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 \ \le 6 \\ x_1, x_2, x_3 \ge 0$$
describe the feasible set of a linear programming problem, it is clear that the notion "extreme points" is from the simplex method. The extreme points under consideration are in one-to-one correspondance with the  basic solutions of the system
eq1 = x1 + 3 x2 + x3 + s1 == 5;eq2 = -x1 + x2 + 2 x3 + s2 == 6;,
where all variables are assumed non-negative. In short words, not going into deep, a basic solution consists of two (the number of the equations) basic variables and three ($5-2$) free variables which equal zero. Variables are basic if the determinant of the matrix of their coefficients in the system does not equal zero. In the case under consideration the result of
Table[Det[CoefficientArrays[{eq1, eq2}, 
Subsets[{x1, x2, x3, s1, s2}, {2}][[j]]][[2]]], {j, 1, 10}]


{4, 3, 1, 1, 5, -1, 3, -2, 1, 1}

means that all tuples of {x1, x2, x3, s1, s2} are basic.
In order to find a basic solution, we choose three free variables and put these zeros and solve the system., for example,
Reduce[{eq1, eq2, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x3 >= 0, s1 >= 0,  s2 >= 0} /. 
{x2 -> 0, s2 -> 0, x1 -> 0}, Reals, Backsubstitution -> True]


s1 == 2 && x3 == 3

We do it as the table, indicating the chosen free variables,
a = Table[Union[Subsets[{x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0, s1 == 0, 
  s2 == 0}, {3}][[j]], {Reduce[{eq1, eq2, x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, 
   x3 >= 0, s1 >= 0, s2 >= 0} /. 
  Subsets[{x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, s1 -> 0, 
     s2 -> 0}, {3}][[j]], Backsubstitution -> True]}], {j, 1, 
   Dimensions[Subsets[{x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0, s1 == 0, s2 == 0}, {3}]][[ 1]]}]


{{s1 == 5 && s2 == 6, x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {False, s1 == 0,  x1 == 0, x2 == 0}, {x3 == 3 && s1 == 2, s2 == 0, x1 == 0,  x2 == 0}, {x2 == 5/3 && s2 == 13/3, s1 == 0, x1 == 0,  x3 == 0}, {False, s2 == 0, x1 == 0,  x3 == 0}, {x3 == 13/5 && x2 == 4/5, s1 == 0, s2 == 0,  x1 == 0}, {x1 == 5 && s2 == 11, s1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {False,  s2 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x3 == 11/3 && x1 == 4/3, s1 == 0,  s2 == 0, x2 == 0}, {False, s1 == 0, s2 == 0, x3 == 0}}

Making use of Menu/Edit/Find..., I manually replace && by ,:
a={{s1 == 5, s2 == 6, x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {False, s1 == 0, 
 x1 == 0, x2 == 0}, {x3 == 3, s1 == 2, s2 == 0, x1 == 0, x2 == 0}, 
    {x2 == 5/3, s2 == 13/3, s1 == 0, x1 == 0,  x3 == 0}, 
{False, s2 == 0, x1 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x3 == 13/5, 
  x2 == 4/5, s1 == 0, s2 == 0, x1 == 0}, {x1 == 5, s2 == 11, s1 == 0,  x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {False, s2 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x3 == 11/3,  x1 == 4/3, s1 == 0, s2 == 0, x2 == 0}, {False, s1 == 0, s2 == 0,  x3 == 0}}

As we see, in some cases the system has no required solutions. To exclude these cases, we consider
b=Select[a,#[[1]]==False&]


{{False, s1 == 0, x1 == 0, x2 == 0}, {False, s2 == 0, x1 == 0,  x3 == 0}, {False, s2 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {False, s1 == 0,  s2 == 0, x3 == 0}}

and
Complement[a, b]


{{s1 == 5, s2 == 6, x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x1 == 5, s2 == 11,  s1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x2 == 5/3, s2 == 13/3, s1 == 0,  x1 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x3 == 13/5, x2 == 4/5, s1 == 0, s2 == 0,  x1 == 0}, {x3 == 3, s1 == 2, s2 == 0, x1 == 0,  x2 == 0}, {x3 == 11/3, x1 == 4/3, s1 == 0, s2 == 0, x2 == 0}}

Next, we sort the above list of lists by variables
Sort /@ %


{{s1 == 5, s2 == 6, x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {s1 == 0, s2 == 11,  x1 == 5, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {s1 == 0, s2 == 13/3, x1 == 0,  x2 == 5/3, x3 == 0}, {s1 == 0, s2 == 0, x1 == 0, x2 == 4/5,  x3 == 13/5}, {s1 == 2, s2 == 0, x1 == 0, x2 == 0,  x3 == 3}, {s1 == 0, s2 == 0, x1 == 4/3, x2 == 0, x3 == 11/3}}

and finally exclude the additional variables s1 and s2 by
Map[#[[3 ;; 5]] &, %]


{{x1 == 0, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x1 == 5, x2 == 0, x3 == 0}, {x1 == 0,  x2 == 5/3, x3 == 0}, {x1 == 0, x2 == 4/5, x3 == 13/5}, {x1 == 0,  x2 == 0, x3 == 3}, {x1 == 4/3, x2 == 0, x3 == 11/3}}

These extreme points are visualised as 6 vertices of the feasible set  which is a polyhedron:
RegionPlot3D[ x1 + 2 x2 + x3 <= 5 && -x1 + x2 + 2 x3 <= 6 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0 &&  x3 >= 0, {x1, -1, 5}, {x2, -1, 5}, {x3, -1, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100]


Edit. Minor language typos.

Such an approach (except visualization) works in higher dimensions too.
