# The default PlotStyle for Plot3D and how to replace the color

Tags: plotting

I would like to know the default `PlotStyle` for `Plot3D`. Below are two codes, one is the default setting and another is my setting.

Default:

```
Plot3D[{z=1/2(x^2+y^2), z=x^2+y^2, z=2(x^2+y^2), z=3(x^2+y^2)},
{x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}, Mesh->None]
```

[image]

My:

```
Plot3D[{z=1/2(x^2 + y^2), z=x^2+y^2, z=2(x^2+y^2), z=3(x^2+y^2)}, 
{x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}, Mesh->None, 
PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]], ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], 
ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[3]], ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[4]]}]
```

[image]

I know there should be some other settings in the default style, such as `Specularity`. I want to use the default style except that use different colors or change the order of default colors.

Comment: ``Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[$PlotTheme, Plot3D]`` -- look for the default plot style.  Also search the site for `ResolvePlotTheme` to find many examples of its use.

Comment: ``defaultplotstyle= "DefaultPlotStyle"/.(Method/. 
   Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D])``

Answer (score 6):

#### Default PlotStyle

```
defaultplotstyle = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
   (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D])
```

[image]

```
p1 = Plot3D[{1/2 (x^2 + y^2), x^2 + y^2, 2 (x^2 + y^2), 3 (x^2 + y^2)},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 300];
 p2 = Plot3D[{1/2 (x^2 + y^2), x^2 + y^2, 2 (x^2 + y^2), 3 (x^2 + y^2)},
   {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> None, ImageSize -> 300, PlotStyle -> defaultplotstyle];
Row[{p1, p2}]
```

[image]

#### and how to replace the colors

> *I want to use the default style except that use different colors or change the order of default colors*

To use a different set of colors, say, `RandomSample[ColorData[43, "ColorList"]]` with the same `Lighting` and `Specularity` settings as the default style, you can modify `defaultplotstyle` as follows:

```
newcolors = RandomSample[ColorData[43, "ColorList"]][[;;4]];
newplotstyle = defaultplotstyle[[;;4]];
newplotstyle[[All, 2]] = newcolors;
```

Using `PlotStyle -> newplotstyle` gives

[image]

To change the order of colors, use, say, `PlotStyle -> defaultplotstyle[[{2, 1, 4, 3}]]` to get

[image]

See also: [search results for ResolvePlotTheme on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ResolvePlotTheme)