# How do I choose in a 3d plot of 2 functions the color of the second one, if I only plot 1 function?

Tags: plotting

Let us consider the following 3d plot:

```
Plot3D[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

resulting in a plot where separate colors are used for each plot. What if I only want to plot one function, but like the color of the second plot in the previous example and want to use it for it? Is there a SIMPLE and NEAT way how to achieve this?

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54632/12) shows how to retrieve the default plot style: ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]``. You can pick the 2nd one to reproduce the blue style you see by default.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you mean Plot3D[x, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[2, "ColorList"]] ? This does not give me the desired result (Mathematica 12.0.0).

Comment: No, use the command form my first comment to get the styles specific to Plot3D. It's not just a colour, it's also some lighting.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I tried putting the command before the mentioned Plot3D command but that did not work either. So how do I use the command? Could you please give me the full code I need to use? Thank you!

Comment: Please read the answer I linked carefully, and in full. It does not tell you to run ResolvePlotTheme before the Plot3D. It explains that you can list the default plots styles with ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]``. Take the 2nd plot style from that output of that command and use it.

Comment: ``Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[
   0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], 
   Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[
      0.196998383`, 0.252204821, 
       0.333209402`]}, {"Directional", RGBColor[
      0.15473514`, 0.21284718`, 
       0.29811516`], ImageScaled[{0, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional",
       RGBColor[
      0.15473514`, 0.21284718`, 
       0.29811516`], ImageScaled[{2, 2, 2}]}, {"Directional",
       RGBColor[
      0.15473514`, 0.21284718`, 
       0.29811516`], ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}]]``

Comment: Thanks, but that is an awfully extensive, complicated way to achieve that. Isn't there a shortcut? I think it is  then better to use the following command with an empty first plot: Plot3D[{"", y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]. I would even put it here as a simple answer, if the question was not closed. What do you think?

Comment: ``Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> ("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]))[[2]]]``

Related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172147/the-default-plotstyle-for-plot3d-and-how-to-replace-the-color

Comment: Or shorter but less readable: ``Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> 
  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D][[5, 2, 4, 2, 2]]]``

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Thank you, that is much better!

Answer (score 3):

Here are three short ways of doing it:

```
defStyle2 = ("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]))[[2]];
defStyle2 = Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D][[-1, -1, 4, 2, 2]];
defStyle2 = Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D][[5, 2, 4, 2, 2]];

Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> defStyle2]
```

For more in depth examples, see these questions:

[What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10/54632#54632)

[The default PlotStyle for Plot3D and how to replace the color](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172147/the-default-plotstyle-for-plot3d-and-how-to-replace-the-color)

Comment: Ok, you were a little quicker:-)

Answer (score 2):

So, with a little "cheating", a solution could be:

```
Plot3D[{"", y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

Longer but without cheating (see WeavingBird1917 comment):

```
 Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> ("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D]))[[2]]]
```

Alternatively,

```
Plot3D[y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot3D][[5, 2, 4, 2, 2]]]
```

See discussion below the question for yet another option.