# Default colors of curves

Tags: plotting

how may I find the name or definitions of colors which are used by default in Plots. I use WM12 ie, if I plot some function it has "blue" colour, next function has "orange" colour. If I need to plot something else corresponding to these curves I would like to use the same colour but I don't know the names of these colours. If I use Blue it is not the same as "blue" used in the plot. Ok, I may choose all colours by me in PlotStyle but do not look for an alternative solution, I'm interested in the default plot colours.

Thank you all, for help.

Comment: The default colors are from `ColorData[97, "ColorList"]`.

Comment: Possible duplicates:https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10,
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/how-to-access-new-colour-schemes-in-version-10.  Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172147/the-default-plotstyle-for-plot3d-and-how-to-replace-the-color

Answer (score 6):

```
defaultplotcolors =  Cases[#, _?ColorQ, All] &[
  "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot])]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
defaultColor = "DefaultColor" /. Themes`DefaultStyles[Plot][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> 97
> ```

```
ColorData[defaultColor, "ColorList"]
```

[image]

**Update:** Default colors for various `PlotTheme`s`:

```
 {#, Cases[#, _?ColorQ, All] &["DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
  (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, Plot])]} & /@ 
  {Automatic, "Marketing", "Business", "Web", "Scientific"} // 
 Prepend[{"theme", "colors"}] // Grid
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make a plot of n functions and extract from the result the color specifications.

E.g. with 3 functions:

t = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];

You may look at "FullForm[t]" and note that there are color specifications in the form of "RGBColors[*,*,_]". You may pick these out by:

```
Cases[t, RGBColor[__], Infinity] // FullForm
```

[image]

or visual:

```
Cases[t, RGBColor[__], Infinity]
```

[image]

Comment: Easier `ColorData[97, "ColorList"]`.